# Nom numérotation sommaire

Tags: nombres, littérature, énumération

Comment appelle-t-on les numéros présents devant les titres d'un sommaire ?

**1.** titre
 **2.** titre
    **2.1** sous titre
    **2.2** sous titre
 **3.** titre
 **4.** titre
 ↑ ça

Comment: L'index du _Bon usage_ utilise ces numéros pour indiquer l'endroit où est discutée chaque entrée. Dans la quatorzième édition, en tête de l'index, se trouve la note suivante: _«Les chiffres renvoient aux **paragraphes**»._ La dénomination me semble à tout le moins discutable, aussi je n'en fais pas une réponse, mais _Le Bon usage_ est une référence très sérieuse qui ne doit pas être sous-estimée.

Comment: Tout dépend de la manière dont est organisé le document. On parle en général de numéros de parties, chapitres, (sous-chapitres), sections, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lorsque l'on met un numéro, il s'agit des *numéros* ou de la *numérotation* (sic).

Mais en pratique, on met également des lettres minuscules ou majuscules, chiffres arabes ou romains, ou combinaisons.

Dans tous les cas, il s'agit d'une **référence** (numérotée, ou par lettre donc ...)

Quand il s'agit de pages, ou de feuillets, il y a un mot particulier: le [folio](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/folio)

Comment: Pourquoi *(sic)* à numérotation ?

Comment: @jlliagre , dire que des numéros = des numéros ou de la numérotation, peut paraître une évidence, mais c'est ainsi (sic).

Comment: Ah, ok. C'est une utilisation inattendue de [*sic*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sic) que j'ai toujours vu suivre la citation d'un mot mal orthographié ou inapproprié, ce que [numérotation](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/num%C3%A9rotation) n'est pas ici.